# How to live streaming from native ios app to youtube account

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, youtube

In objective C is their any SDK which helps to broadcast video in YouTube live streaming ? where user can comment on live video.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lots of API for different programming languages. Here you can find the list [YouTube APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/libraries) and there is the Objective C on the list, also you can find a few example code. And maybe [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) site helps for you to get started with live streaming.